# How to fetch every possible media types

Tags: http, http-headers, media-type

Having a resource identified by the URL `https://example.com/resource`, accepting `image/svg+xml` and `text/html` media types (using HTTP's Accept header).

How can a client be aware of those possible media types?
We frequently refer to Accept header as a *negotiation* between the client and the server. But I don't really understand how the client can give to the server its wanted type, and how the server is supposed to answer.

I think the server may be able to teach to the client its allowed types.

Comment: What's the context of this? You're expecting a `GET` on `https://example.com/resource` and wish to let the requesting client know there are other representations of that resource available?

Comment: Well, send a `415 Unsupported Media Type` on the wrong content, and clients could read the `Accept` header and alter it's behavior based on that. But without prior knowledge, and no first request, there's no way of determining beforehand what the resource supports.

Comment: But the `Accept` header is only available as a request, from the client to the server, right?
What could the server return in order to give to the client the possible values? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Doug: You can pass a set of `Link` headers with each response to let the client know of alternative representations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this needs to be split up:

If you are a *server* and wish to inform clients about alternative representations of the requested resource, you can do so via the `Link` header as described in [RFC 5988](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988). A possible response could look like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Ok
Content-Type: image/svg+xml
Link: <https://example.com/resource>; rel="alternate"; type="image/png"
Link: <https://example.com/resource>; rel="alternate"; type="image/jpeg"
```

If a *client* fetches a resource and wants to know which alternative representations are available, this were the way to go if no `Link` headers can be found:

1. Fetch the resource and send an `Accept` header containing `*/*`, implying every imaginable media type were understood by the client.
2. Extract the media type from the response and add it to your Accept header with a weight `q=0`, letting the server know the served media type were not acceptable. Example:

   `Accept: image/svg+xml;q=0, */*`
3. Send out a new request for the same resource with the new accept header created in step 2
4. If you receive a `406/Not acceptable` response, you're done. If not: Go back to step 2.

You should now know all media types for the given resource on the server.

Comment: I've updated my answer to contain the correct link type `alternate` instead of the invalid type `alternative`. cf [RFC 5988, scetion 6.2.2](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5988#section-6.2.2).